# Is there any way to set week start from monday in ngx-bootstrap datepicker in angular 8?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am using angular 8. I am trying to use week start from Monday in ngx-bootstrap datepicker. Please help...

Thanks in advance.

```
<input
    bsDatepicker
    type="text"
    class="date"
    ngModel
    [bsConfig]="datePickerConfig"
    style="padding-left: 30px"
    (ngModelChange)="date($event)"
    [value]="newDate"
    style="width: 140px; padding-left: 38px"
/>
```

Comment: could you fix it?

Answer (score 4):

NOTE: I am using Angular 12!

The only way I know to make the week start from a different day is to use [locales](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#locales).

So, in your case you should add in the **app.module.config** (or what module you want):

```
import { defineLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
import { enGbLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';

defineLocale('en-gb', enGbLocale); // before @NgModule({})
```

And then in the component where you need the date to start from another week day to inject the BsLocaleService:

```
constructor(private localeService: BsLocaleService) { }
```

and in ngOnInit you need to say use 'en-gb':

```
this.localeService.use('en-gb');
```

This should do the trick :) I hope it will help.

Comment: Official document didn't helped me. You did! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm read through their documentation, and the source code (of the datepicker) and the sad answer is:

"no, I'm afraid there isn't (an obvious) a way of specifying that"

However, it seems that ng-bootstrap does indeed have an API for selecting the starting day of the way. Have a look at their API documentation:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api

please notice the `firstDayOfWeek` input-parameter, as it seems to exactly fit your needs.

I'm not sure it's the answer you're looking for, since switching from ngx-bootstrap to ng-bootstrap may not be an option for you (and your team) - and the task can be less that trivial.